# NumberFormatException readJavaFormatString on Samsung devices only

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception, decimalformat

I'm trying to make a custom `SeekBar`, I've a method called `getValue()` as below :

```
  public double getValue() {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
            df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
/*Line 40*/   Double value = (max - min) * ((float) getProgress() / (float) getMax()) + min;
            value = Double.valueOf(df.format(value));
            return value;
    }
```

For some reason, the app crash on Samsung devices when I call the `getValue()` method :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException:
  at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString (FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble (FloatingDecimal.java:110)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble (Double.java:543)
  at java.lang.Double.valueOf (Double.java:506)
  at abc.ui.views.FloatSeekBar.getValue (FloatSeekBar.java:40)
  at abc.ui.activities.PhotoEditorActivity$2.onProgressChanged (PhotoEditorActivity.java:431)
```

Where I should start to investigate in order to fix this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe the Samsung device uses a different locale and expects a comma instead of the dot as the decimal symbol? Can you test that? That's just a wild guess though. Can you print the String value that the parsing failed on?

Comment: @f1sh thank you so much for the hint, I will test it right now